# Issue in login to WSO2 API Publisher with LDAP configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apacheds

I have configured Apache DS user store in WSO2 3.0.0. All the user store configuration I have given in deployment.toml file. I have created an user in DS with DN: cn=apiadmin,ou=users,dc=wso2,dc=com. After WSO2 server started I am trying to login to API Publisher with user apiadmin and password. It authenticated successfully but after that the page refreshing automatically and doesn't redirected to the APIs page. In log getting the below error. Can anyone help me in understanding the issue.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-29 18:42:32,136]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} - An instance of org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.APIMTokenIssuer is created for Identity OAuth token generation.
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:34,196] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:34,551] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:35,893] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:36,176] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:37,262] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:37,403] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2020-01-29 18:42:38,676] ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
```

Below is the user store configuration from deployment.toml:

```
[user_store]
class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager"
type = "read_write_ldap"
#type = "database"

[user_store.properties]
MaxUserNameListLength="100"
ConnectionURL="ldap://<local machine ip>:10389"
ConnectionName="cn=apiadmin,ou=users,dc=wso2,dc=com"
ConnectionPassword="admin"
UserSearchBase="ou=users,dc=wso2,dc=com"
UserNameSearchFilter="(&amp;(objectClass=person)(cn=?))"
UserNameListFilter="person"
UserNameAttribute="cn"
ReadLDAPGroups="false"
GroupNameAttribute="cn"
GroupNameSearchFilter="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))"
GroupSearchBase="ou=users,dc=wso2,dc=com"
GroupNameListFilter="(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
PasswordHashMethod= "PLAIN_TEXT"
AnonymousBind= "false"
WriteGroups= "true"
MembershipAttribute= "member"
UserRolesCacheEnabled= "true"
ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin= "true"
```

Apache DS:
[image]

Thanks,
Surodip

Comment: What are the roles which are assigned to the apiadmin user? (Check from the api-manager management console)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Menaka. But I am not able to login to the management console also after I have setup UserStore as ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager in deployment.toml.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the DS configuration? This could be due to a simple misconfiguration of the user store.

Comment: any help on this from anyone?